# Awk: understanding how comments are removed in php

Tags: bash, awk

Apologies in advance for a rather simplistic question.

In a big pile of "note to self", I have this little awk one-liner that **works** perfectly for my needs, which is to remove comments from a php file. But I would like to better understand it:

`awk '/^\/\*/{c++} c!=1; /^ \*\//{c++}'`

I cannot, unfortunately, find the original post in order to better understand how it works.

Googling it turns up a ton of things on c++ but not the original post. Neither [Explain Shell](https://explainshell.com/) nor [Symbol Hound](http://symbolhound.com) has helped.

I don't particularly stumped by the `{c++} c!=1;` bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: initial value of variables in numeric context is `0`... so the first time `c++` is executed, it will have value `1` and then `2` and so on ... `c!=1` is separate block of code not related to `{c++}` block... when `c` is not `1`, condition will be true and input record will be printed(default action).. see http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/ for more such idioms

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer! So it is actually using c++, it's not an Awk annotation? I have that site you mentioned bookmarked but I could not see c++ in it. Hence being lost.

Comment: Since it increases the value of var `c` (`c++`) at the beginning and the end of a comment marker (`/*` and `*/`) and prints comparing `c` with 1, it only removes the first comment.

Comment: @Farhang it has nothing to do with the language C++, it using the letter `c` for a counter and incrementing it each time a multi-line comment beginning is found, e.g. each time a `/*` is found and when the close, e.g. `*/` is found.

Comment: Thank you David. I thought that it could not be related to c++ but then again I worried I was missing something bigger. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your `awk` script and it does not work properly!!!
You should use the following one to remove :

```
 gawk '/^\/\*/{c++} c!=1; /^.*\*\//{c=0}' php_file
```

to remove `/* comments */` multi-lines comments or single lines with only `/* comments */`!!!

**TESTED on:**

[image]

In a nutshell,

- `awk` will read the input file line by line and will do its default action: *printing*
- when the condition `/^\/\*/` is met ( `/*` comment that is directly located at the start of the line) the block `{c++}` will be executed!, in `awk` variable are by default initiated to 0, so after the block `c=1` and `c!=1` will be `false` so nothing will be printed.
- as long as we are in the comment section `c!=1` will be `false` so nothing will be printed.
- then we reach the last line of comment and c is set back to 0, so from the following line everything will be printed again.

**REMARK:**

- lines with commands followed `/* */`  are still printed as-is
- `//` comments are not removed
- If there are some super important commands on the same line directly following a comment block **they will be lost**!!!

  ```
  /* comment starts
  /* still some comments
  end of comments */some super important commands;
  ```

**IMPROVEMENT:**

- change `c=!1` by `c<1` to improve the stability of the script, with `c!=1` your script will stop functioning properly in the case:

  ```
  /* comment starts
  /* still some comments
  end of comments */
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Not only it helped for the actual awk, I am grateful that you explained it so clearly. Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome! :-) `awk` and `sed` are very powerful tools to help you manipulating files (and more especially code/settings files), when you have time I can only recommend you to deepen your knowledge of those tools it will improve your productivity!!